# Prolog -- Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to check for even/odd players and even/odd columns in a game by counting the players and the columns. At some point, it seems I am not instantiating my variables correctly.
Here is how I call the game:

```
playGame(Game):- 
    countPlayers(Game,TotalPlayers),
    colSize(Game,TotalCols),
    checkEvens(TotalPlayers,TotalCols);
    checkOdds(TotalPlayers,TotalCols).
```

I assume the issues lies with TotalPlayers and TotalCols not being assigned correctly.

I tried looking at other questions, however the problems seem to be different. I am new to prolog and likely making a trivial mistake somewhere.

After some tracing, it seems the error is being caused when a combination of odd/even is the input. Given an input of two even or two odd numbers, the program behaves as expected. Given an input of one odd and one even number, and it breaks.

Full error:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] 1 is _34862 mod 2
ERROR:   [10] checkOdds(_34894,_34896)
```

Comment: The `mod` operator requires that all of it's arguments be instantiated. It won't "solve for x" in `1 is X mod 2`. What query did you enter?

Comment: I'm passing in the Players and Cols. These are collected in the columnsAndPlayers predicate as TotalPlayers and TotalCols and passed in. So then I assume these variables weren't instantiated?

Comment: I wasn't looking for a general description. I mean what query exactly did you enter when you got the error? And, yes, you can see in your error message that neither `Players` nor `Cols` are instantiated (they show up as anonymous variables, `_34894` and `_34896`).

Comment: My bad. My query was: columnsAndPlayers([[2,4,1],[2,1,4],[1,1,3],[1,2,2]]).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't put numbers on the left side of `is/2`. The operational semantics of `is/2` is to _evaluate_ the arithmetic expression on its right, then _unify_ its numeric value with the term on its left. It makes no sense to have `1 is .....`

Comment: Another issue with your code: all these parentheses are totally unnecessary and just weird to see. You should put parentheses if you use a disjunction though (`;`). Never write those at the ends of lines.

Comment: Altogether, I don't know if you really should have a semicolon after `checkEvens(TotalPlayers, TotalCols)`

Comment: @Boris Thanks for all the feedback, it will certainly be helpful as I continue learning. As far as this question goes, you were right with the semicolon; changing that to a comma resolved this error. I will need to look into that more before I try using it again.

Comment: See my "answer". I don't know how you _meant_ the semicolon, or what you think the commas do, and so on. Better read some more.

Comment: Please don't remove the code you had there! I wouldn't have been able to spot your error without looking at all the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?- X = 3, between(1, X, 2), between(1, X, 3).
X = 3.

?- X = 3, between(1, X, 2); between(1, X, 3).
X = 3 ;
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] between(1,_7656,3)
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Can you spot what is going on?

---

A predicate like this:

```
foo :- a, b; c.
```

is the same thing as:

```
foo :- a, b.
foo :- c.
```

In other words, `a, b` is indeed in a different "context" than `c`.

Often, you mean to say `a, (b ; c)` instead. This is why the `;` is usually put at the beginning of the line, and you do use parens around it. So it would be either

```
(   a,
    b
;   c
)
```

or

```
a,
(   b
;   c
)
```

(which is not the same thing!)

This is definitely confusing:

```
a,
b;
c
```

You don't see "good" Prolog code written like this (say library code).

But really, try to read a textbook or something, Stackoverflow is good for figuring out where your error is but not for really learning.

Comment: So here, I think the X is out of scope on the second one, since it had already executed the first part.